Not able to connect local geoserver in local mapstore2
I've started learning mapstore and have stuck in this issue of not able to connect my geoserver (localhost:8085) on mapstore (localhost:8082) .
When I checked the network tab , I'm getting following error
Type Exception Report

Message Servlet.init() for servlet [HttpProxy] threw exception

Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

Exception
avax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet.init() for servlet [HttpProxy] threw exception
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:679)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:617)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:934)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Root Cause

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLSContext
    java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:315)
    java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.getImplClass(Provider.java:1918)
    java.base/java.security.Provider$Service.newInstance(Provider.java:1894)
    java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:236)
    java.base/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
    java.base/javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:168)
    org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.createDefault(SSLContexts.java:51)
    org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.getSocketFactory(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:194)
    org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.getDefaultRegistry(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:116)
    org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.<init>(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:123)
    it.geosolutions.httpproxy.HTTPProxy.init(HTTPProxy.java:135)
    org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:483)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:93)
    org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:679)
    org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:617)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:63)
    org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:934)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1698)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:52)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
    org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)


I have attached error screenshot.


What does the log file say?

added photo in the question

Please add the actual text not a picture of it

yup, already added in the question

Looks like your SSL certificate is incorrectly set up in tomcat

actually I don;t have SSL, I'm trying to connect local mapstore with local geoserver

Well it looks like MapStory is trying to create a SSL connection when it fails.

is there any document stating steps to connect geoserver WMS to mapstore ?
